# Как установить сертификат SSL на DJANGORESTFRAMEWORK

Tags: linux, django, apache, ssl, django-rest-framework

Мужчины большая проблема! Установил SSL на сайт через certbot ,HTTPS как я понял не может кидать запрос на http поэтому переделывает его под https , а сервак DJANGORESTFRAMEWORK работает на http
( python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:668 ) определенный порт сделать под SSL certbot видимо не позволяет,
Как лучше сделать? Помогите пожалуйста весь день сижу с этим, видел решение создать субдомен но как я туда поставлю SSL если apache не будет работать а будет DRF (они конфликтуют), и на https DRF не могу попасть даже вырубив apache ПОМОГИТЕ ПРОШУ! (UBUNTU 20)
[image: ошибка SSL]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Надеюсь вы уронили исключительно свой хостинг, а не рабочий, в противном случае лучше попросите откатить вам бэкап
2. Без логов апача не ясно, что пошло не так, покажите логи
3. А причём здесь сервер DRF?
4. Посмотрите следующие видео, может поможет https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhidVhNHfeU
5. И да, без логов вам не помогут.

Comment: К сожеление это боевой, сервер то работает на http работает прекрасно, но как только ставлю ssl бесплатный vue работает хорошо, но сервер DRF  (python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:668) который на порту 668, не защищен, как можно сделать? wsgi как то поможет думаете?